# referencing a vector

Tags: c++, reference, tokenize

I have this code

```
void split(vector<float> &fvec, string str)
{
    int place = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            if(str.at(i) == ' ')
            {
                fvec.push_back(atoi(str.substr(place,i-place).c_str()));
                place=i+1;
            }
        }
        fvec.push_back(atoi(str.substr(place).c_str()));
}
```

What im trying to do is pass a reference to a vector into the method so it splits the string i give it into floats without copying the vector... i dont want to copy the vector because it will be containing 1000's of numbers.

is it not possible to pass a vector by reference or am i just making a stupid mistake?

if it helps heres the code im testing it out with

```
int main (void)
{
    vector<float> fvec;
    string str = "1 2 2 3.5 1.1";

    split(&fvec, str);

    cout<<fvec[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obviously, something isn't happening the way you expected, or you wouldn't be posting this.  For that something, what did you expect, and what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed possible. You're just using the wrong syntax. The correct way to do it is :

```
split(fvec, str);
```

What you're doing is wrong because it passes the address of the vector as the intended reference.

Comment: Still getting to grips with C++, thanks for your help. just to check, if i have void method(int &x) i only have to pass in an int, such as method(int)?

Comment: Yes. The call will look the same. You can't know if `method(bob)` passes bob by value or by reference. You have to look at the method's definition.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a modern compiler, like gcc/g++, it does named return value optimization for you, so that you don't need to pass the return value by reference or pointer.

See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization/

http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: +1; this is the better approach, instead of passing in an existing vector as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the address of the vector. (`split(&fvec, str);`)

The call should be `split(fvec, str);` without the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing that leaps out is the `split(&fvec, str);` in your `main` function, which means you're not passing a vector but the address of a vector.  This is the right thing to do if your vector parameter is a pointer, but not if it's a reference.  Use `split(fvec, str);` instead.

Also, one thing you might consider is building the vector in the function and returning it as normal.  This is likely to be optimized out by the compiler.  If you're not using a compiler with return value optimization ability, you're likely to get better results by changing compilers than trying to tune your code manually.

And, if you're worried about passing big data structures around, what of the string parameter?  Doesn't that get large?

Comment: very large... im making a COLLADA loader for a uni project, so there are strings of floats for vertices and normals, which i need to store and display using opengl. i had this working before where i was creating an object that had a vector in it, but i didnt think i needed a whole class... so instead i want to write individual methods depending on if im splitting a string of string, floats or ints